# Setting DataContext of a view from markup with parameterized constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a wpf application using MVVM(MVVM Light). My view is having a property token which is passed to my viewmodel in the constructor like this.

```
DataContext = new ChartNewViewModel(Token);
```

I want to set my data context from xaml using markup.For all those viewmodels which has default parameterless constructors, I used this

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ChartNewViewModel></viewModel:ChartNewViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
```

I don't know how to pass parameter in the constructor of viewmodel using xaml.

Answer (score 4):

XAML 2006 has a limited support for non-default initialization through initialization text. However `ObjectDataProvider` can be used for a workaround

here you go

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="viewModel:ChartNewViewModel">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <model:Token />
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.DataContext>
```

If you are using XAML 2009 then you can use `x:Arguments` directive

example

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ChartNewViewModel>
        <x:Arguments>
            <model:Token />
        </x:Arguments>
    </viewModel:ChartNewViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
```

`x:Arguments` is a feature from XAML 2009 only.

more on [x:Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382)

Comment: You forgot to mention that XAML 2009 is only supported on Xamarin. WPF and others completely lack XAML 2009 support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Messenger class of MVVM Light Toolkit for this case. I assume that your Token type is string.

Send your parameter:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(Token);
```

In ChartNewViewModel.cs

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, GetToken);

private void GetToken(string token)
 {
   this.Token = token;
 }
```

Comment: I am already done with this thing and app is working fine for it. I just want to pass the token from markup.

Comment: you can't use constructor with parameter in XAML. Define a dependency property in ChartNewViewModel and set it from XAML.